# How to sanitize the document.referrer in java script based apps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkmarx

I am trying to sanitize the `document.referror` in the react component like below.
However, the Checkmarx security scanning tool complains about it. I tried `sanitize-html` also but did not work. Any ideas?

```
const checkURL = string => {
  try { 
    return new URL(string)
      }
  catch (error) 
    { return 'invalid' }
}

<MyComponent
 action={()=>window.location.href = checkURL(document.referrer)+"/Home" }
</MyComponent>
```

Checkmarx:
Client-DOM error:

This untrusted data is embedded straight into the output without proper sanitization or encoding, enabling an attacker to inject malicious code into the output.

Comment: What is the message from Checkmarx?

Comment: updated. the error shows in the document.referror

Comment: Pretty much any use of `document.referrer` is a bug waiting to happen. Consider a URL parameter instead, like `?ret=/some/page`, which you can parse and extract the path component from.

Comment: check `window.encodeURIComponent` or `escape`

Comment: Thank you all. Thanks, @ibrahim tanyalcin, it worked!